# How to use @JsonIgnore to be applied only when the object is not the root object?

Tags: java, spring, rest, jackson

I am working on a REST based JAVA project using Spring framework. Some of my JPA entities have `@JsonIgnore` annotation from jackson for the properties. Example below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TRANSACTION")
public class Transaction {

    @Id
    @Column(name="SERIAL", length=16)
    private String serial;

    @Column(name="NARRATION", length=128)
    private String narration;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="transaction", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<TransactionDetail> details;

  // other fields goes here

}

@Entity
@Table(name="TRANSACTION_DETAIL")
public class TransactionDetail {

    @Id
    @Column(name="UUID", updatable=false)
    private String uuid;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="FK_TRANSACTION")
    private Transaction transaction;

    @Column(name="ACCOUNT_NO")
    private int accountNo;

  // other fields goes here

}
```

As per the above class relationship, I want the `@JsonIgnore` to be applied only when I fetch `Transactions`.

```
List<Transactions> transactions = transactionsRepo.findAll()
```

But If I am directly fetching the TransactionDetails, I need the property `transaction` in `TransactionDetail` to be fetched as well.

```
List<TransactionDetail> details = transactionDetailsRepo.findByAccountNo(accountNo);
```

How can I use the `@JsonIgnore` to do this? Or else is there any other proper way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Entity
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Table(name="TRANSACTION_DETAIL")
public class TransactionDetail {

    @Id
    @Column(name="UUID", updatable=false)
    private String uuid;


    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="FK_TRANSACTION")
    private Transaction transaction;

    @Column(name="ACCOUNT_NO")
    private int accountNo;

  // other fields goes here

}
```

You can try using fetchtype as lazy , what this does is it will fetch the property in Transaction Detail Entity. but it will not fetch the related data of transaction_detail which means all of the other ones will be null. you can annotate your entity with @JsonInclude as I did to include only non null values.
and please add jackson-datatype-hibernate Jar files or if you are using maven add the dependencies in pom file

Comment: let me know if this is what your requirement is?

Comment: The reason I put `@JsonIgnore` is, that it creates a loop when I load the Transactions and convert to JSON. But, when I load the TransactionDetails, I need this field to be present in JSON. I hope your reply might help. I will test it and update.

Comment: @Madu, After making the above changes, I am getting the following error `Could not write JSON document: could not initialize proxy - no Session ` It is like jackson wants to go through all fields and the session is already closed.

Comment: Great!. Fortunately, I was able to find out the missing `jar` which is required to carry out this task. `jackson-datatype-hibernate` has to be in my library for this to work. I added and it is good now. Please edit your answer to include that library and remove `@JsonIgnore` then add `@JsonInclude(what ever here)`. I will select your answer.

Comment: Thank you @Madhu. And this blog post was somewhat helpful when fetching objects with complex relationship. http://blog.encodez.com/tips/jackson-bidirectional-relationship-the-right-way-preventing-infinite-recursion-exception-with-java-jackson